# Raspberry PI GCC 4.8.2 build boost 1.56 atomic error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost

i tried to build the 1.56 boost library with c++11 on my raspberry pi. The most libraries are building correct, but boost atomic generates following error:

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.

> ```
> Component configuration:
>
>     - atomic                   : building
>     - chrono                   : not building
>     - container                : not building
>     - context                  : not building
>     - coroutine                : not building
>     - date_time                : not building
>     - exception                : not building
>     - filesystem               : not building
>     - graph                    : not building
>     - graph_parallel           : not building
>     - iostreams                : not building
>     - locale                   : not building
>     - log                      : not building
>     - math                     : not building
>     - mpi                      : not building
>     - program_options          : not building
>     - python                   : not building
>     - random                   : not building
>     - regex                    : not building
>     - serialization            : not building
>     - signals                  : not building
>     - system                   : not building
>     - test                     : not building
>     - thread                   : not building
>     - timer                    : not building
>     - wave                     : not building
>
> ...found 129 targets...
> ...updating 8 targets...
>
> gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/lockpool.o
> g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=cxx11’
>
>     "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -fPIC -std=cxx11 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/lockpool.o"
> ```
>
> "libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp"
>
> ```
> ...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi/lockpool.o...
> ...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8/release/threading-multi>libboost_atomic.so.1.56.0
> ```
>
> for lack of
>   lockpool.o...
>       ...skipped libboost_atomic.so.1.56.0 for lack of libboost_atomic.so.1.56.0...
>       ...skipped libboost_atomic.so for lack of libboost_atomic.so.1.56.0...
>       gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/lockpool.o
>       g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=cxx11’
>
> ```
>     "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthread -std=cxx11 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_SOURCE -DBOOST_ATOMIC_STATIC_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/lockpool.o"
> ```
>
> "libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp"
>
> ```
> ...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/lockpool.o...
> ...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_atomic.a(clean)
> ```
>
> for lack of
>   lockpool.o...
>       ...skipped libboost_atomic.a
>   for lack of
>   lockpool.o...
>       ...skipped libboost_atomic.a for lack of libboost_atomic.a...
>       ...failed updating 2 targets...
>       ...skipped 6 targets...

I did:

```
./bootstrap --with-libraries=atomic 
./b2 cxxflags="-std=cxx11"
```

Anyone has an idea what i can do?

Comment: isn't the flag `-std=c++11`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is known and fixed there:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10446

https://github.com/boostorg/atomic/commit/415db7054723291042e4ff1ffa8fdd5bc8b07163

Answer (score 2):

The correct flag is `-std=c++11`, not `-std=cxx11`. Just run your command with:

```
./b2 cxxflags="-std=c++11"
```

Comment: I am sorry i mean -std=c++11 mistypes here, I did the command with the right flag otherwise i get an error because of the flag. But i found the solution i add it as answer